# Why this inconsistency between a Dataframe and a column of it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

When debugging a nasty error in my code I come across this that looks that an inconsistency in the way Dataframes work (using **pandas** = 1.0.3):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10*k, 11, 22, 33] for k in range(4)], columns=['d', 'k', 'c1', 'c2'])
y = df.k
X = df[['c1', 'c2']]
```

Then I tried to add a column to `y` (forgetting that `y` is a Series, not a Dataframe):

```
y['d'] = df['d']
```

I'm now aware that this adds a weird row to the Series; `y` is now:

```
0                                                   11
1                                                   11
2                                                   11
3                                                   11
d    0     0
1    10
2    20
3    30
Name: d, dtype...
Name: k, dtype: object
```

But the weird thing is that now:

```
>>> df.shape, df['k'].shape
((4, 4), (5,))
```

And `df` and `df['k']` look like:

```
 d   k  c1  c2
0   0  11  22  33
1  10  11  22  33
2  20  11  22  33
3  30  11  22  33
```

and

```
0                                                   11
1                                                   11
2                                                   11
3                                                   11
d    0     0
1    10
2    20
3    30
Name: d, dtype...
Name: k, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things at work here:

- A `pandas` series can store objects of arbitrary types.
- `y['d'] = _` add a new object to the series `y` with name `'d'`.
- Thus, `y['d'] = df['d']` add a new object to the series `y` with name `'d'` and value is the series `df['d']`.

So you have added a series as the last entry of the series `y`. You can verify that

- `(y['d'] == y.iloc[-1]).all() == True` and
- `(y.iloc[-1] == df['d']).all() == True`.

**To clarify the inconsistency between `df` and `df.k`:** Note that `df.k`, `df['k']`, or `df.loc[:, 'k']` returns the series 'view' of column `k`, thus, adding an entry to the series will directly append it to this view. However, `df.k` shows the entire series, whereas `df` only show the series to maximum length `df.shape[0]`. Hence the inconsistent behavior.

I agree that this behavior is prone to bugs and should be fixed. View vs. copy is a common cause for many issues. In this case, `df.iloc[:, 1]` behaves correctly and should be used instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm now aware of that. My surprise comes from the fact that now `df` and `df['k']` are out of sync; or, better, that it was **allowed** to get out of sync.

Comment: Good catch. That is because `df['k'], df.k, df.loc()` are views, not copy. I agree that the behavior seems buggy here. The view of `df` should be restricted to the maximum length `df.shape[0]`. You may want to raise this issue on github.

Comment: @user21338 If you open an issue, please take care to use a more direct example to show the cause. That would help it be noticed and resolved more quickly.

Comment: Maybe I do, but I thought my example was simple enough. Please, what will you do to make it simpler?

Comment: @user21338 For instance, `y['new_name'] = 'new_value'`. So that the code is self-explained and the issue at interest is disentangled from the weird entry value in `y`. At least that is for me, and I know that someone more experienced will have even simpler way to clearly convey the issue.